# SQL count largest per category 3 tables

Tags: sql

Table film

```
film_id   title   description   release_year   language_id
```

Table : `category`

```
category_id   name   last_update
```

Table : `film_category`

```
film_id   category_id   last_update
```

How to get 5 category film with the largest film ?
I want to show the result is `category.name` and `count of film in category`

Comment: WHERE IS LARGEST COLUMN?

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result and your `RDBMS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to type this on my phone while on a bus so I can't check it. But this should be what you need.   Will do a better job when I get home

```
Select top 5 c.name, count (fc.film_id)
From film_category as fc
Inner join category as c 
    on c.category_id = fc.Category_id
Group by c.name
Order by count (fc.film_id) desc
```

Comment: great. Its work. but I remove `TOP 5` because my syntax error and I change that with `LIMIT 5`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select b.name, a.count 
from category b
inner join (
    select Top 5 category_id, count(film_id) as count
    from film_category 
    group by category_id order by count(film_id) desc) a 
  on a.category_id = b.category_id
```

Comment: Dont you need include an `order by count(film_id) desc` so top 5 choose the biggest?